# ViewComponent View was not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created an ASP.NET Core MVC (.net core 8) project. I added a dummy ViewComponent and each time I run the application, I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Components/Dummy/Default' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Components/Dummy/Default.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Components/Dummy/Default.cshtml
```

I've checked MicroSoft documentation and I've checked on forums like StackOverflow but nothing is working.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here is the solution explorer view:

[image: Solution explorer]

Here is the ViewComponent class:

```
public class DummyViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public DummyViewComponent()
    {
  
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));

        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is the CSHTML:

```
<div>
    Dummy view component!
</div>
```

And here is where it is being invoked in the home (index) page:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Overview";
}

@section Styles {
   
}

@await Component.InvokeAsync("Dummy")

@section Scripts {
    
}
```

As you can see, this is quite straight forward - I really cannot see where the issue is.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysConfused,  Could you pls share your Program.cs? And did your view contain any other html code? What you have done seems no mistake. The project structure is correct. Maybe it is better for you to share a minimal repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done seems no mistake. Here are some potential causes and solutions you could try:

1. Runtime compilation is not enabled by default, install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package and modify the Program.cs:

   ```
   builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
   ```
2. Try to specify the view path:

   ```
   public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
   {
       await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
       return View("~/Views/Shared/Components/Dummy/Default.cshtml");
   }
   ```
3. Check if there are any issues with the compilation of your views. If you cannot troubleshooting for this, you can remove all of the other html codes except the view components and then check if it works or not.
4. Right-click the file(`Views/Shared/Components/Dummy/Default.cshtml`) in Visual Studio, select `Properties`, and verify the `Build Action` is set to **Content**.
5. Try to right-click the project, choose `Clean` and then choose `Rebuild`. After doing the two approaches, run the application again.
6. Check if you write any customized middlewares or filters which may influence the view components.

Comment: Hi Rena! Thanks for your response. I tried all the above with no success, except for #4 - this resolved the issue. My next question would be: do I need to set this every time or is there a setting that can be configured? Either way, thank you for your help - I was going mad :-)

Comment: Hi @AlwaysConfused, actually it is Content by default when you create a razor view, not sure if any settings or you did any operation to make it not be Content. But you can have a try like this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/a/27970807/11398810

Comment: Strangely, after manually changing the Dummy ViewComponent view page to "content", each new ViewComponent view page is now automatically "content". So, not sure what happened. Anyway, thanks again. Obviously, if this ever happens again, I'll know how to fix it.